# How to find error in compile time instead of execution time in referenced DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, project, compile-time

In Solution 1 i have a project with name **MainProject** this project referenced to Another Project with Name **Model** and a **DLL**(assembly) with name **Presentation**.

This DLL building in another **solution**, This Solution Contains **Presentation** project and **ModelPerim**(this project have same assembly with Model Project) project. In Presentation project i worked with ModelPrim.

***Question:***

In MainProject If exist Conflict with Model (such as a **property** in ModelPrim **Not exist** in Model) this conflict raised in **execution time**, How to i know this conflict in ***compile time***?!

Hope i can to illustrate this problem:

[image]

Comment: There may be multiple ways of solving your problem. If possible I would strongly suggest that you make model and modelperim the same library and reference that project in both your solutions. If that is not possible you could set up a build server that run unit tests to spot inconsistencies. The tests could be written to compare both libraries. Yet another solutions would be to make a code generation template that would generate modelperim from model or wise versa.

Comment: @mortb you should really post that as an answer.

Comment: @mortb Thanks for your answer, first way is not possible, second and third way is costly for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple ways of solving your problem.

If possible I would strongly suggest that you make model and modelperim the same library and reference that project in both your solutions.

If that is not possible you could set up a build server that run unit tests to spot inconsistencies. The tests could be written to compare both libraries.

Yet another solution would be to make a code generation template that would generate modelperim from model or wise versa. You would run that (automatically if possible) when you make changes generate a new "clone".

Answer (score 0):

I reference Model dll instead of ModelPrim project in solution2 and then build solution2, So conflict props were seen.